# curl set dynamic header token throws invalid key

Tags: bash, curl

Im trying to hit a rest api with token in header.

```
apikeyName="$(date '+%s')"
key=$(curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                    -d '{"name":"'$apikeyName'", "role": "Admin"}' \
                    http://admin:admin@localhost:3000/api/auth/keys | jq '.key')

echo $key
# # Alerting API
curl -k -X GET 'http://localhost:3000/api/alert-notifications' -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$key'';
```

Terminal output

```
"eyJrIjoiaWJPaDFFZXZMeW1RYU90NUR4d014T3hYUmR6NDVUckoiLCJuIjoiMTY3NTM1OTc4OCIsImlkIjoxfQ=="
{"message":"invalid API key","traceID":""}
```

First 1 is the key printing and last one from api response. I tried to hardcode the key and it works.

Comment: Doubt you want quotes on the key, try `jq -r '.key'`

Comment: Yes, and it's giving you a value with embedded quotes as shown in `echo $key`. `jq -r` will produce the response value without quotes.

Comment: you can answer it, i will accept now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Use `jq -r '.key'` to extract the key from the json response without adding quotes to it.

Long answer: There is a difference between quotes on the command line and quotes embedded in a variable. Consider:

```
key='"abcd"'
printf '%s\n' $key "abcd"
# prints:
# "abcd"
# abcd
```

Quotes on the command line are bash syntax. Bash notes what is being quoted and then removes the quotes from the command line when it's done, thus `printf` only prints `abcd` in the second case above.

Quotes inside a variable are plain old data. Bash doesn't do anything with them, so they get passed through to the command like any other data and `printf` prints `"abcd"` in the first case.

In your `curl` case the receiver doesn't expect the key to have quotes embedded in the data. So, `curl -blah "keydata"` works fine because bash takes the quotes out, but `curl -blah $key` fails because bash does NOT remove the embedded quotes.

See also: [BashParser](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser)